# Google Maps Remote .js and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I wrote a Google Maps API wrapper in JS, did some local tests with static html, and everything worked just fine. Then I loaded the files into a local web server running in localhost:8080, tested the map panels, and once again, everything worked just fine.

Then a week went by, I added a map to a page, and I couldn't get it to load. Nothing has changed (that I know of anyway, obviously something has), and static tests continue to work just fine, but when I try to load the API from the server I get this in the debug console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false.
Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I read a bit around, but I still can't understand the error, much less fix it. Can someone please give me a hand?

**edit:** I use a simple  tag to load google's js. No jQuery, no nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Santiago hopefully I can help you now :) The error you are receiving is due to Google's prohibiting of cross site scripting. You can find the info here: [Google](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) which also references:[Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
It looks like you'll need to create a proxy service for your client on your public facing webserver. Since the request comes from your public webserver and the reply goes back to your webserver it will meet the same domain requirements that Google requires. I do not know enough python yet to create a pythonic cgi proxy but I have to think that there are many different solutions out there already. Plus you will be limited by your server as to what type of solution you employ.

HTH!
~MWR